# Drop data from database every 15 mins, but getting an error -- Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, scheduled-tasks

For example, I have a card called 'JIMR1' and after every 15 mins it drops a code from the database table. When I run this code it shows the error `can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine`  . I added the print, it shows the code without any problems, but only when I try to send the code it has problems.

```py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def startc(self, ctx):

        channel = ctx.channel.id
        self.client.scheduler.add_job(self.cardDrop, CronTrigger(minute='0, 15, 30, 45'), args=[channel])
     
    async def cardDrop(self, channel):

        cards = db.column("SELECT Code FROM cardsHand")

        card = random.choice(cards)
        print(card)
        await self.client.fetch_channel(channel).send(card)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await self.client.fetch_channel(channel).send(card)
```

split this up to

```
channel = await self.client.fetch_channel(channel)
await channel.send(card)
```